# How to Transmit a View Entry Count to a Class Method

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I'm having trouble with usage of a count of the number of entries in a view. I especially need to know when there are no entries in the view. I have placed debug code in the view below and the view count `currants.curItem.count`is updating as expected. The count status in checkForUpdates() doesn't follow the view above.

If I recall correctly I should be using @EnvironmentObject or @ObservedObject only in a view. I really need some kind of global variable that I can pass to the method checkForUpdates. It is crashing when count in checkForUpdates() is nonzero when in the view it is actually zero. It also crashes in checkForUpdates() with the error Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Currencies found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Currencies may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

```
struct manCurView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var currants: Currants
    
    var body: some View {
        List {       
            ForEach(currants.curItem, id: \.id) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.curCode)
                        .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Text(item.cunName)
                }
                .font(.subheadline)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: removeItems)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Manage Working Blocks"), displayMode: .inline)
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: addCurView()) {Text("Add Working Blocks").fontWeight(.bold)}
                .font(.title2)
                .disabled(currants.curItem.count > 7)
```

Here is how the data is stored for the view above

```
struct CurItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var cunName: String 
    var curName: String
    var curCode: String
    var curSymbol: String 
    var curRate: Double
}

class Currants: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var curItem: [CurItem]   
}
```

And here is the class and method where I would like to use count from the view manCurView

```
class BlockStatus:  ObservableObject {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var globalCur : Currants
    @ObservedObject var netStatus : TestNetStatus = TestNetStatus()
    
    func checkForUpdates() -> (Bool) {
        
        if netStatus.connected == true {
            if globalCur.curItem.count > 0 {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is very difficult to give you exact code but you can try something like the code below in your `manCurView`

```
@StateObject var blockStatus: BlockStatus = BlockStatus()

.onChange(of: currants.curItem.count, perform: { value in
            print("send value from here")
            blockStatus.arrayCount = value
        })
```

And adding the code below to `BlockStatus`

```
@Published var arrayCount: Int = 0{
    didSet{
        //Call your method here
    }
}
```

Look at the code below.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
struct CurItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
}
class Currants: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var curItem: [CurItem] = [CurItem(), CurItem(), CurItem(), CurItem()]
}
class TestNetStatus: ObservableObject {
    static let sharedInstance = TestNetStatus()
    @Published var connected: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        //Simulate changes in connection
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true){ timer in
            self.connected.toggle()
        }
    }
}
class BlockStatus:  ObservableObject {
    @Published var arrayCount: Int = 0{
        didSet{
            checkForUpdates()
        }
    }
    @Published var checkedForUpdates: Bool = false
    var netStatus : TestNetStatus = TestNetStatus.sharedInstance
    //private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        //Maybe? if you want to check upon init.
        //checkForUpdates()
        
        //Something like the code below is also possible but with 2 observed objects the other variable could be outdated
        
        //        cancellable = netStatus.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] in
        //            self?.checkForUpdates()
        //        }
    }
    
    func checkForUpdates() {
        if netStatus.connected == true {
            if arrayCount > 0 {
                checkedForUpdates = true
            }else{
                checkedForUpdates = false
            }
        }else{
            checkedForUpdates = false
        }
    }
}
struct ManCurView: View {
    @StateObject var currants: Currants = Currants()
    @StateObject var blockStatus: BlockStatus = BlockStatus()
    @StateObject var testNetStatus: TestNetStatus = TestNetStatus.sharedInstance
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("checkedForUpdates = " + blockStatus.checkedForUpdates.description).foregroundColor(blockStatus.checkedForUpdates ? Color.green : Color.red)
            Text("connected = " + blockStatus.netStatus.connected.description).foregroundColor(blockStatus.netStatus.connected ? Color.green : Color.red)
            
            ForEach(currants.curItem, id: \.id) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.id.uuidString)
                        .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Text(item.id.uuidString)
                }
                .font(.subheadline)
            }
            //Replaced with toolbar button for sample
            //.onDelete(perform: removeItems)
            //When the array count changes
            .onChange(of: currants.curItem.count, perform: { value in
                blockStatus.arrayCount = value
            })
            //Check when the networkStatus changes
            .onChange(of: testNetStatus.connected, perform: { value in
                //Check arrayCount
                if blockStatus.arrayCount != currants.curItem.count{
                    blockStatus.arrayCount = currants.curItem.count
                }else{
                    blockStatus.checkForUpdates()
                }
            })
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Manage Working Blocks"), displayMode: .inline)
        //Replaced addCurView call with toolbar button for sample
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing, content: {
                Button("add-currant", action: {
                    currants.curItem.append(CurItem())
                })
            })
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading, content: {
                Button("delete-currant", action: {
                    if currants.curItem.count > 0{
                        currants.curItem.removeFirst()
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Lorem: I added the @StateObject and .onChange logic to manCurView.  I getting errors for Type 'RateStatus' has no member 'onChange' and Cannot use instance member 'currants' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.  checkForUpdates is called before calling an API-- I can't call it from didSet. I can't call the API if manCurView count is 0

Comment: There is no sample code on `RateStatus` so I can't comment on that other than .`onChange` is a SwiftUI method it gets called from the `body` of the `View`. Like I said before without a minimal reproducible product; something I can copy and paste and see everything; I can't help you specifically. Create sample code with the same function in a separate project and all code should be in the same file.

Comment: Look at the code above so you can see an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is ContentView: Notice in the menu that because this is a view I can use count directly to disable entry input. Down in getData() notice that I'm calling blockStatus.checkForUpdates() to determine if is OK to call the API. A fault will occur if currants.curItem.count = 0

I just realized that technically getData() is part of the ContentView so I can change the call below to `if blockStatus.checkForUpdates() == true && currants.curItem.count != 0 {`

I'm going to spend some time studying your suggestions above to see if I could use this in the future.

So thanks for all the help by looking into this. I wasn't aware of the suggestions on code displayed on Stackoverflow. I'll be sure to follow those guidelines in the future.  Galen

import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Combine

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @EnvironmentObject var currants: Currants
    @EnvironmentObject var blockStatus: BlockStatus
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (alignment: .center) {
                
                Text("Title")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Group {
                    NavigationLink(destination: entryView()) {Text("Entry")}
                    .disabled(currants.curItem.count == 0)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: totalView()) {Text("View Totals")}
                    
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: listView()) {Text("View Entries")}
                    
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: xchView()) {Text("View Dates")}
                }
                
                Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 130)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .font(.title2)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: NavigationLink (destination: settingsView()) {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .font(.system(.title3))
                
                
            }, trailing: NavigationLink( destination: aboutView()) {
                Text("About")
            })
            .onAppear(perform: getData)
        }
    }
    
    
    func getData() {
        
        // check criteria for updating data once daily
        if blockStatus.checkForUpdates() == true {
            
            print("  doing update")
            
            ---- API HERE -----



            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```